# asp.net intranet application slow for non domain users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

We have an intranet application using Windows Authentication. The application is very responsive when users from inside the domain accesses it. However when i try to reach it from a device outside the domain it takes ~45 seconds per page.

Windows Authentication is the only enabled form of authentication on the IIS, NTLM is the only enabled provider.

I have attached a screenshot from fiddler, showing quite a few 401's.

[Screenshot from fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL9Ya.png)